# How exposed am I using older Firefox version (56)?

Tags: firefox

Due to one add-on not being compatible with newer Firefox versions (57 and up), I'm stuck with Firefox 56 (running on Debian) for a while.

I'm OK with things like performance or looks not being the best you can get. However, I am worried about security issues and wonder how dangerous it is.

Should I choose Firefox 52 ESR instead of the Firefox 56?

Answer (score 2):

The versions and security fixes are listed here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox/

While it is not recommended to run older versions with known issues, one way you might be able to get along is to run the old Firefox in a container or virtual machine in order to get some protection for your personal data on your host.

Comment: I think this is a fantastic approach. That being said, [VMware’s vuln this week](https://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2018-0030.html) temporarily  tempers my own vehemence on the matter slightly.